# How to use thumbnails in gallery?

Tags: functions, theme-development, gallery

Since Wordpress 5.x they've removed the thumbnail size option for galleries. Is there a way to activate or build a workaround? I like to build up a classic Lightbox gallery.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a project going on about the image sizes. You can follow it [right here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/6177).

Right now, you can try using **shortcode_atts_gallery** filter. Take a look at these codes to get a hint:

```
/* Register shortcode_atts_gallery filter callback */
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_gallery', 'meks_gallery_atts', 10, 3 );

/* Change attributes of wp gallery to modify image sizes for your needs */
function meks_gallery_atts( $output, $pairs, $atts ) {

/* You can use these sizes:
- thumbnail
- medium
- large
- full
or, if your theme/plugin generate additional custom sizes you can use them as well
*/

$output['size'] = 'medium'; //i.e. This will change all your gallery images to "medium" size

return $output;

}
```

You can find more information about **shortcode_atts_gallery** [right here](https://mekshq.com/change-image-thumbnail-size-in-wordpress-gallery/).

Comment: Nice idea but that is for Wordpress 4.x ... There is no gallery tag using anymore. Its a new WYSIWYG Block Editor Element.

Answer (score 1):

It's an ongoing process. Right now there is not a way to adjust manually the image sizes on the gallery block. It is being discussed by the WordPress core development community on [this github issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/6177).

Just because the default gutenberg gallery block does not allow you to do it does not mean you cannot install a 3rd party plugin, create a custom block yourself (I recommend using ACF Custom Blocks), or reverting to the classic editor for this specific use.

Comment: Okay thanks. I guess I'll downgrade to 4.9.9 for the time of waiting :)

Comment: To be clear you don't need to downgrade to 4.9.9 to use the classic editor. You can install the Classic Editor Plugin.